# put two table in same line html

Tags: php, html

how i supposed to put two table in same line ? this codes below show my table go to the new line. please help me . i want in html

this is my tables . i want put them in one line

[image]

and this is my codes

```
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><b>#</b></td>
        <td><b>Request ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Title</b></td>
        <td><b>Importance</b></td>
        <td><b>Date</b></td>
        <td><b>Status</b></td>
        <td><b>View/Reply</b></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $a=1;
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE req_status = 'UNDONE' ORDER BY req_status DESC,req_important ASC,req_dateReceive DESC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $a; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_important']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_dateReceive']; ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo $row['req_status']; ?></b></td>
        <?php
        if( $row['req_status'] == "UNDONE") { ?>
            <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=reply&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "reply.jpg" height="65" width ="80"></a></td>
        <?php
        }
        else { ?>
            <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=view&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "view2.jpg"></a></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $a++;
    } ?>
    </table>

    <td>
    </td>


        <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><b>#</b></td>
        <td><b>Request ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Title</b></td>
        <td><b>Importance</b></td>
        <td><b>Date</b></td>
        <td><b>Status</b></td>
        <td><b>View/Reply</b></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $a=1;
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE req_status = 'DONE' ORDER BY req_status DESC,req_important ASC,req_dateReceive DESC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $a; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_important']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_dateReceive']; ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo $row['req_status']; ?></b></td>
        <?php
        if( $row['req_status'] == "UNDONE") { ?>
            <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=reply&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "reply.jpg" height="65" width ="80"></a></td>
        <?php
        }
        else { ?>
            <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=view&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "view2.jpg"></a></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $a++;
    } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS; your PHP is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: look carefully. there are my html codes. that <td > <tr> . =='

Comment: I can see your HTML *interspersed among the PHP*, however it's irrelevant to your question. We only need the rendered HTML and your CSS.

Comment: i want to know if i doing something at td and tr can i make it in one line ? without using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non CSS solution. (as requested)

Make one table, and place each table within a cell that naturally falls into columns

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <!-- LEFT TABLE -->
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <!-- RIGHT TABLE -->
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

It would be better to float some divs as columns instead though

CSS

```
.floatLeft {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="floatLeft">
  <table></table>
</div>
<div class="floatLeft">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

---

Comment: ok i got it . but how to make outside table invisible ? it kinda messy .

Comment: if you have styles applied to all tables and it is apply to the newly created table, apply styles only to the children tables using a class

Comment: so how to help that outside table invisible ? i should declare that table class different than table class in css above right?

Answer (score 1):

```
display:inline-table;
```

[Demo Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/0y4u02q5/).

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
table.twoinline {
   width: 49%
}

<table class="twoinline">
...
...
...
</table>
<table class="twoinline">
...
...
...
</table>
```

Comment: yes just use it like this: <table style="width: 49%;">

Comment: where should i declare this table style ? above <table> ?

Comment: no, you need to replace your current tables from <table border="1"> to <table style="width: 49%; border: 1px">

Comment: i already try your codes. but it still in different line. should i reduce the width ?

Comment: i try reduce the width . nothing happened. should i change that tr and td ?

Comment: temporary remove the images to try, maybe they are messing with the widths

Comment: i already remove image link , still same , table below wont move. hmmm. i even reduce the width to 10 %. still didnt move a bit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? (indentions bad):

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
         table { border: 1px solid black;float:left;width:148px;}
     #table_container{width:300px;margin:0 auto;}
</style>

    <div id="table_container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Request ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Importance</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>View/Reply</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $a=1;
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE req_status = 'UNDONE' ORDER BY req_status     DESC,req_important ASC,req_dateReceive DESC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $a; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['req_title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['req_important']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['req_dateReceive']; ?></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $row['req_status']; ?></b></td>
    <?php
    if( $row['req_status'] == "UNDONE") { ?>
        <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=reply&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "reply.jpg" height="65" width ="80"></a></td>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=view&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "view2.jpg"></a></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tr>
<?php
$a++;
    } ?>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Request ID</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Importance</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>View/Reply</th>
</tr>
<?php
$a=1;
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE req_status = 'DONE' ORDER BY req_status DESC,req_important ASC,req_dateReceive DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $a; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['req_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['req_title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['req_important']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['req_dateReceive']; ?></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $row['req_status']; ?></b></td>
    <?php
    if( $row['req_status'] == "UNDONE") { ?>
        <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=reply&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "reply.jpg" height="65" width ="80"></a></td>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <td><a href="viewRequestAdmin.php?var1=view&var=<?php echo $row['req_id']; ?>"><image src = "view2.jpg"></a></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $a++;
    } ?>
  </table>

  </div>
```