# mpdf float not working for tables

Tags: mpdf

I noticed that float not  working in mpdf.
In pure html, code below work fine,

Help be appreciate,
Thanks

```
<?php

$html = '
<html>
<head>

<style>
.section_left {

  float : left;
    width: 40%;
}
.section_right {
   float : right;
   width: 40%;

}
#customers
{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: '.$font_taille_corps.'pt;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

#customers tr {
    background-color: #d7dce1;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    height:30px;
}

</style> </head>
<body>';

$section_left = "<table id='customers' style='page-break-inside: avoid; ' class='section_left'  ><tr><td>Hello world</td></tr></table>" ;

$section_right = "<table id='customers' style='page-break-inside: avoid; ' class='section_right' ><tr><td>Some others word</td></tr></table>" ;
```

//I don't want to put table in div, because MPDF slip data in 2 pages

```
$html.= $section_left.$section_right;

define('_MPDF_PATH','mpdf/');
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',20,15,50,25,10,5);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output("test.pdf", "I");
exit;
```

[enter image description here]
When printing, this is result, not I whant
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPepA.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [put two table in same line html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769524/put-two-table-in-same-line-html)

Answer (score 1):

Floating for tables is not supported in mPDF.

For mPDF, I'd recommend using a single table with the two "subtables" as its cells (either as child table elements or as plain row/column combinations).

See https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html in mPDF documentation.